# Hive Query is not working as expected

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying a left join in Hive Query, but it does not seem to work. It returns me columns only from left table:

```
 create table mb.spt_new_var as select distinct customer_id ,target   from mb.spt_201603 A
     left outer join mb.temp B
     on (A.customer_id=B.cust_id);
```

I tried selecting few records from table B based on the some random customer_id from table A and it returns some records. But if I try the left join on table A, it returns me only columns from table A. The data-type of both the IDs is same(int). what could be the possible reason behind this?

Sample Table A:

```
Customer_account_id target
12356                1
34245                0
12356                1
....                ..
```

Sample Table B:

```
Cust_id   col1 col2 col3
12356     ..   
12567     ..
24426     ..
...
```

Table A has some 1m records, while table B has some 30m records. There is possibility of some duplicate IDs in table A and Table B.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and the results you are getting (and what you expect).  Your description of the `left join` sounds like the way it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused.  Hive is returning the columns that you specify in the query:

```
select distinct a.customer_id, a.target 
from mb.spt_201603 a left outer join
     mb.temp b
     on a.customer_id = b.cust_id;
```

If you want columns from the second table, you need to select them:

```
select distinct a.customer_id, a.target, b.col1, b.col2
from mb.spt_201603 a left outer join
     mb.temp b
     on a.customer_id = b.cust_id;
```

Comment: I am trying, a,customer_id,a.target,b.* , but it is throwing error :TOK_ALLCOLREF is not supported in current context

Comment: In other databases, selecting something from table A and then doing left join works. Its just that I needed to specify the b.cols as well. Thanks!